# Laravel 4.2 Form-Model Binding with Select Boxes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've created a `select`dropdown element, but I can't get it to be pre-populated by the value persisted in my back-end model.

```
{{ Form::select('marketplace_id', [
            "A1PA6795UKMFR9" => "DE",
            "A1RKKUPIHCS9HS" => "ES",
            "A13V1IB3VIYZZH" => "FR",
            "APJ6JRA9NG5V4" => "IT",
            "A1F83G8C2ARO7P" => "UK"
        ], 'marketplace_id') }}
```

The form is opened with

```
{{ Form::model($config, array('url' => '/reputation/setup' )) }}
```

All other bindings, (all be it to `text` fields) are working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a real value or variable with real value. For example, instead of this:

```
], 'marketplace_id') }}
```

You should do this:

```
], $marketplace_id) }}
```

Or this:

```
], 'A13V1IB3VIYZZH') }}
```

Comment: Almost correct, and certainly helped me work it out. The `$marketplace_id` variable isn't in scope as its a property of `$config` i.e. `$config->marketplace_id` works. Thank you.